# PHP code doesn't return any results from MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with connecting MYSQL to my search fields. PHP code looks logical but it doesn't show any results. Direct search in MYSQL is working absolutely fine. But when it comes to website search it doesn't work.

I removed/swapped host, user, password, dbname before i pasted here.

Thank you for all the help!

```
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('HOST','USER','PASSWORD','DBNAME');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"DBNAME");
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Nname</th>
<th>City/Village</th>
<th>Oblast</th>
<th>Language</th>
<th>Download</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['cityvillage'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['oblast'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['language'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['download'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
```

Comment: the problem is most likely in how that GET is being fetched/populated. you need to show us the full picture here.

Comment: `if(isset($_GET['q'])) { $q = intval($_GET['q']); } else { echo "It is not set."; exit; }` or `!empty()`

Comment: echo $sql after you set it. Also after your query executed. Do mysqli_error to see if you get any error from MySQL.

Comment: you also don't need `mysqli_select_db($con,"DBNAME");` you already declared it here `$con = mysqli_connect('HOST','USER','PASSWORD','DBNAME');`

Comment: he is using mysqli @SerhatAkay

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));` should there be a db issue. Use error reporting also http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - you now have enough to debug; since we have no idea where your GET is coming from and how. *Good luck*

Comment: Voted to close as unclear.

Comment: If you have a form or any `HTML` please show it.

Comment: Why does this look next to indentical to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100132 ?

Comment: i agree with you @Fred-ii-

Comment: @CodeGodie Both look and smell *fishy*. Hardly a coincidence, *unless....* oh well, you saw the other comments ;-)

Comment: Thank you for all the help guys. Much appreciated! @Fred-ii-, that is my friend working on the same project asked the question without knowing that i asked same thing here. How can we merge these?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$q."'";
```

To this:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '$q'";
```

Your concatenation and dropping out of the query appears to be causing some problems.

Note you are vulnerable to sql injection.  Since you are using mysqli, you may wish to consider using [mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: I don't think it would matter. MySQL should compensate for it.  But... but... I could be wrong, however I have seen this often. OP's question is unclear and I have voted as unclear till we know exactly where that GET is coming from. You could be right though ;-)

Comment: (addendum to above) It would however make a difference if OP's column isn't an `int`; that would do it though.

Comment: Good point;  it could be the GET statement.   @spiderzaur try echoing out `$q` before the query

Comment: ah yes. also remove `intval()` unless `id` is actually an int

Comment: @Fred-ii- regarding the concatenation:  I've sometimes found that because of double quoting, it starts to behave strangely if you jump in and out (not entirely sure)

Comment: Real hard to say without seeing how that GET array/value looks like. If there is misuse of `intval()` and isn't that and they're trying to pass a string... well, that would do it. They're probably also trying to pass `John's coffee house`, who knows ;-) if so... MySQL is *probably* complaining in the background with all ears covered and doors slammed shut. ;-)

Comment: One more thing @spiderzaur it's a bad idea to use GET for user ids;  it's another way to break in to your app.  Set them as session ids, and then grab them as `$_SESSION['id']`

Comment: Lookie what just popped up http://stackoverflow.com/q/32100132/ - hardly a coincidence, or someone found this question and wants to submit an answer in order to solve it here.